# Is it still wrong to do navigation first, content later websites?

Tags: html, css, seo, grid

I know all the classical SEO articles have a chapter about how important it is to have the content before anything else (like navigation), and recommends us to implement the craziest CSS hacks, just to be sure that our content is before anything else.

On the other hand I'd really like to start using grid systems for my new project, and the grid system I like doesn't support reverse order, like how 960.gs does. So it means that my HTML needs to have a structure like this:

```
<div header>
<div vertical-nav>
<div middle>
  <div horizontal-nav>
  <div content>
</div>
<div footer>
```

My question is that is Google really that stupid not to figure out things like this? I mean that company has maybe the most intelligent algorithms on Earth... Do we really need to hack our websites just because we think it makes it easier for Google to read it? I'd naturally think that good meta tags, titles and URLs are much more important; but I'm not an expert on this field.

Does a website with the structure above could get good SEO results, supposing meta, title and URL is implemented well?

Comment: I have no reference for this, which is why it's just a comment. *Google (now) doesn't care. in. the. slightest if your navigation comes before your content.* This is perhaps a question for Webmasters?

Comment: I agree with thirtydot, Google doesn't care one bit (from experience.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this (using CSS absolute positioning), specifically to answer that question.

My findings were that moving the navigation below the content did *marginally* affect the equity assigned to the main navigational links. However, it had no measurable impact to rankings of the content or pages.

This was done on a relatively small site (<1000 pages) with a homepage PR of 6 at the time. I've yet to test it on larger sites, but see little value in doing so.

Having tested other navigational changes on much larger sites (10m+ pages with homepage PR of 8), i can tell you that content is NOT king, it's queen - site architecture is King (but we all know how a king with out the queen never rules) :)

Answer (score 2):

No one will ever prove difinitively one way or the other, and Google likely won't tell, but SEO is pretty much voodoo once you get beyond the basics.

Just make sure you have an interesting website that will gain organic deep links, and your PR will rise.

Links and keyword density/keyword research are the most important SEO tips. If you're vying for such a hotly contested keyword that you need to worry about micro optimizations, maybe you should work your way down the long tail  a little bit (freelance brickmason in miami rather than freelance brickmason)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be interested in an area 51 site that is being set up (if you havent already):
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1/white-hat-seo?referrer=sSvHQ-Cm3Lk1

Personally, I think it doesn't matter how your site is structured.

For me the content is king and using meta tags correctly play an important role in helping to index your pages properly; not only with Google, but with all the other search engines out there.

The ordering your links before content or via-versa shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of chatter now is about Google segmenting pages and treating sections differently. Such as menus, footers, main content, side bars. This indicates they are way beyond the old issue that what comes first is most important.

HTML5 also introduces new semantic ways to indicate those sections.